# Apache Superset Donut Chart Total Label Color

Tags: css, colors, label, apache-superset, donut-chart

I need to change the "Total" label color inside the donut chart, but the chart is inside a canvas so I can't target the label's specific css class.

This is a pie-chart (donut chart) in apache superset. I want to change the color on superset with css or something.

[image]